# Refer to control from function

Tags: java, android

You'll have to bear with me here as I'm sure this is asked all the time, but I didn't manage to search it.

If I have a minimal android application and I seemingly have to declare all my controls in an event like onCreate, how do I then refer to these controls in functions given that these controls aren't initialized until the app is 'created'?

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public void myFunction(){
    myButton.setText("Java is hard")
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.designerbutton);
}
```

Do I have to pass the controls as arguments every single time I call the function?  That seems a bit unwieldy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it as an attribute like any other Java object

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button myButton;

    public void myFunction(){
        myButton.setText("Java is hard")
    }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.designerbutton);
   }
```

Comment: They're called fields or instance variables, not attributes.

Comment: No, they are attributes of the containing object so it's fine to call them that, otherwise they are referred to as member variables. But thanks for adding so much value.

Comment: The thought to declare a control prior to assigning it to..  a control (I'm still not sure of the terminology here) never struck me.  That would make sense.

Comment: Are you new to OOP? It's not sequential so it's new concepts, if you're new to OOP as well as Android then it's definitely going to be helpful to read a bunch of tutorials first

Answer (score 1):

Read up about [Member variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html):

> There are several kinds of variables:
>
> - Member variables in a class—these are called fields.
> - Variables in a method or block of code—these are called local variables.
> - Variables in method declarations—these are called parameters.
>
> The Bicycle class uses the following lines of code to define its fields:

```
public int cadence;
public int gear;
public int speed;
```

> Field declarations are composed of three components, in order:
>
> - Zero or more modifiers, such as public or private.
> - The field's type.
> - The field's name.
>
> The fields of Bicycle are named `cadence`, `gear`, and `speed` and are all of data type integer (int). The public keyword identifies these fields as public members, accessible by any object that can access the class.